# Firefox Save to PDF?

Tags: firefox, pdf, firefox-extensions

On my Nexus 7 running Android, I've installed Firefox. One thing I really love about it, is that it enables me to save websites as PDF right out of the box. Now I'd like to do the same thing in Firefox on my Ubuntu 12.04LTS desktop. Do I need an extension for this, and if so, can someone recommend one?

I know I can Print to PDF, but that's not entirely the same.

Comment: In firefox, `Tools -> Add-ons` in the search bar just input the word "pdf". There you should be able to look at available addons related to pdf files and to your question, just choose the one that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might try the add-on "save as pdf":
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-as-pdf/

Comment: Didn't work for me. Couldn't find the UI element to use it.

Comment: As of 11/15/2016, the average of 136 reviews is 2 stars... not recommendable (even less if you read the reviews).

Comment: I guess it used to work for older versions of FF. For me I tried today with FF version 60, but it didn't worked for me.
So, I guess this answer is outdated.